# H2O Connection Error: HTTP 403 Forbidden

Tags: linux, ssh, proxy, http-status-code-403, h2o

I am currently trying to run an H2O Server Instance on a external ssh Machine(Linux) from Python.

But I get the following Error when running `h2o.init()`:

```
H2OConnectionError: Could not establish link to the H2O cloud http://127.0.0.1:54321 after 20 retries
[02:43.11] H2OServerError: HTTP 403 Forbidden:
```

So the Server is running and the Error fires at testing the Connection. I think this has something to do with Proxy-Settings. But I don't know how and where to configure.

Any help?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you need to unset the “http_proxy” environment variable.

so:

```
del os.environ[“http_proxy”]
```